# Getting Request body content using Retrofit 2.0 POST method

Tags: android, request, okhttp, retrofit2, jsonresponse

I have a requirement to get a request body and to perform some logic operations with Retrofit 2.0 before doing `enque` operation. But unfortunately I am not able to get the post body content from my service call. At present after searching a lot I found only one solution like `logging` the `request` that I am posting using Retrofit 2.0 from [this method](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses) by using `HttpLoggingInterceptor` with `OkHttpClient`. I am using the following code to log the request body in the Android Logcat:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();  
       logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    httpClient.interceptors().add(logging);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    return retrofit.create(apiClass);
```

**Problem I am facing with the above method:**

1. Request body are seen only on the default Android Logcat like

`02-04 01:35:59.235 5007-5035/com.example.retrofitdemo D/OkHttp:{"nameValuePairs":{"id":"1","name":"chandru","type":"user"}}`

But the above method returns only response body in the logcat, I am not able to get it as either `String` or `JSONObject`. Eventhough if I could able to get the response body using `HttpLoggingInterceptor`, my request body will be shown in the Logcat with the tag "OkHttp" all the time even after the application goes into the production (So primarily this leads like a kind of relieving the post data in the logcat).

**My Requirement:**

I need to get the request body as `String` or `JSONObject` or whatever method without reviling the post data in the Logcat.

**What I tried:**

I tried to fetch the request body even after `onResponse` from `Response<T> response`, but though I couldn't able to get it done possible. Please find the code that I am using for this purpose as follows:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String responseString =  gson.toJson(response.raw().request().body());
```

**Note:** The above converted request body using `gson.toJson` method returns only the meta data not the request post data.

Kindly help me with this by providing your valuable tips and solutions. I have no idea how to do this. I am completely stuck up with this for the past two days. Please forgive if my question is too lengthy. Your comments are always welcome. Do let me know if my requirement is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get the solution for this, m also facing problem with this

Comment: No not yet. Let me know if you get any.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I have got it working from this link
[Retrofit2: Modifying request body in OkHttp Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791244/retrofit2-modifying-request-body-in-okhttp-interceptor)

```
private String bodyToString(final RequestBody request) {
            try {
                final RequestBody copy = request;
                final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
                if (copy != null)
                    copy.writeTo(buffer);
                else
                    return "";
                return buffer.readUtf8();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                return "did not work";
            }
        }
```

Retrofit dependencies i am using are

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
```

Comment: I am adding following versions in build.gradle

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'

Comment: it helped me, but why do you need to create a local variable with the param?  final RequestBody copy = request;

Comment: it was hit and try for me at that time u are free to optimize ;)

Comment: For people downvoting, new retrofit dependencies have been updated please check them

Comment: @RafaelLima if you use SonarQube it suggest to operate on new filed rather than on method parameters, it suggest to keep it unmodified.

Comment: Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I too had the similar issue, I had set JSON as @Body type in retrofit, so the namevaluepair appears in front of the raw body, and it can be seen inside the interceptor.
Even though if we log/debug the jsonObject.toString we see the request as correct without the namevaluepair presented.

What i had done was by setting

```
Call<ResponseBody> getResults(@Body JsonObject variable);
```

and in the calling of the method i converted the JSONObject to JsonObject by

```
 new JsonParser().parse(model).getAsJsonObject();
```