# post parameter that passed in as @Field does not being added into RequestBody in Retrofit2?

Tags: retrofit2

base on Retrofit @Field doc, when making a post request

a combination of using @FormUrlEncoded and @Field will yields a request body of: paramName=paramValue&paramName=paramValue.

but what I am not getting field paramemters included in RequestBody.

my interface definition as below:

(I have no endpoint, and jake Wharton says use ./ as explicit intent that you want to use the path of the base URL and add nothing to it, but I tried @POST("./") it's not work, i got 404 not found error, so I add full url address to bypass this error temporarily)

```
public interface BannerService {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("http://10.10.20.190:6020/router")
Flowable<List<BannerBeanList.BannerBean>> getBannerData(@Field("method") String method, @Field("adspaceId") String adspaceId);
```

}

and this is how I make calls to interface service:

```
public class RemoteListDataSource implements RemoteDataSource {
@Override
public Flowable<List<BannerBeanList.BannerBean>> getBannerListData(ADFilterType adFilterType) {
    BannerService bannerService = RetrofitHttpManger.getInstance().create(BannerService.class);
    return bannerService.getBannerData("mz.app.ad.list", String.valueOf(adFilterType.getValue()));
}
```

}

below is retrofit instance in it's private constructor

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(httpClientBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            //TODO baseurl tempororily hard code for test purpose
            .baseUrl("http://10.10.20.190:6020/router/")
            .build();
```

this is the result I got:

[image]

the current request body that I am logging is the common parameters that I added from FromBody in interceptor, **only except the parameters that I passed in from @Field annoation**, and server side info tells the same thing.

Comment: you are adding form parameters in an interceptor too?  Are you sure you are not accidentally replacing the the request body instead of adding to it?

Comment: @iagreen thanks for your reminding, I am actually replacing the request body instead of appending paramemters to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue, thanks to @iagreen's comment.

**the request body was replaced by FormBody.Builder().add().build() which passed into chain.request().newBuilder().post().build() in my interceptor**.

then the question turns out to be how to append paramemters in RequestBody, and the solution can refers to [Retrofit2: Modifying request body in OkHttp Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791244/retrofit2-modifying-request-body-in-okhttp-interceptor)