# Is there a way to add add form data in every request

Tags: android, retrofit, interceptor, form-data

I have multiple requests that repeate same form data fields, Is there any way to add these fields once in an interceptor or something else.

How my requests looks like

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("endpointone")
Call<ResponseOne> requestRemoveFromCart(@Field("myParamOne") int myParamOne,
                                        @Field("repeatingParamOne") int repeatingParamOne,
                                        @Field("repeatingParamTwo") int repeatingParamTwo);


@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("endpointtwo")
Call<ResponseTwo> requestSetQty(@Field("myParamTwo") int myParamTwo
                                @Field("repeatingParamOne") int repeatingParamOne,
                                @Field("repeatingParamTwo") int repeatingParamTwo);
```

Now, I don't want to add repeatingParamOne and repeatingParamTwo in every single request, is there any way where I can add it once.

Note : I know we can add query parameters in interceptor but my question is weather we can also form data field or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791244/retrofit2-modifying-request-body-in-okhttp-interceptor

Comment: Really helpfull... Thanks